# Setting ContentType on StringEntity or HTTP request?

Tags: android, http-post, content-type, http-put

I am having a dilemma here: this is confusing to me.

**Code**

```
StringEntity stringEntityInstance = new StringEntity("some string", "UTF-8");
HttpPost req = new HttpPost("myurl");
req.setEntity(stringEntityInstance);
```

- If add `code A` then I face some JSON error from API
- If add `code B` then I don't face any issue.

**Code A**

`stringEntityInstance.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,”application/json"));`

**Code B**

`req.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,”application/json");`

Any help is appreciated !